# MySQL - How to select rows where datetime field is not equal to 0000-00-00 00:00:00?

Tags: mysql

Here is my table "tb_posts":

[image]

I want to select only those rows where datetime field i.e. post_date_published is not equal to 0000-00-00 00:00:00. I am using following query but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM `tb_posts` WHERE `post_date_published` IS NOT NULL
```

I am getting the same output as shown in the above picture.

Why `IS NOT NULL` is not working?

Comment: `0000-00-00 00:00:00` is definitely not NULL. You should use `<>` operator `post_date_published <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00'`

Comment: @LukaszSzozda oh you mean either I should use `<>` or `!=`

Comment: @navjotsingh Please re-read my question once again, I don't need rows with 0.

Comment: Try SELECT * FROM tb_posts where post_date_published != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [MYSQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)  it saves invalid dates as '0000-00-00 00:00:00'. It will not be considered as NULL.

Try comparing with the date '**0000-00-00 00:00:00**':

```
SELECT * FROM tb_posts where post_date_published != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

A method I use with this sort of thing is

```
SELECT `columns` FROM `tb_posts` WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`post_date_published`) > 0
```

From the [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp):

> The valid range of argument values is the same as for the TIMESTAMP
>   data type: '1970-01-01 00:00:01.000000' UTC to '2038-01-19
>   03:14:07.999999' UTC. **If you pass an out-of-range date to
>   UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), it returns 0**.

The `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function forces the result to be an integer so it's much easier to work with in these quick comparisons. It is also vital for working with **MySQL 5.7** where "empty" (ie zero value) date/time columns are not allowed.

(*I had a lot of grief trying to convert various date columns to `NULL` because MySQL 5.7+ didn't recognise  `0000-00-00 00:00:00` as a valid comparison -- so I converted it to a unix timestamp so as to compare the **timestamp** rather than the actual [invalid] **date**.*)